# Instantiate a nib throws NSException swift 3

Tags: swift3, runtime-error, xib, nib, nsexception

i'm trying to instantiate a xib, this is the exception(too generic) :

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   **NSException**

I assigned the class CustomBottomSheetPanel to the **file owner** (file inspector section) of my **xib**

here my mycode:

```
class CustomBottomSheetPanel: UIView {

    class func instanceFromNib() -> CustomBottomSheetPanel {
        return Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomBottomSheetPanel", owner: self, options: nil)![0] as! CustomBottomSheetPanel
    }

}
```

I also tried

```
UINib(nibName: "CustomBottomSheetPanel", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! CustomBottomSheetPanel
```

and also to set both **self** and **nil** in **owner** property

So what is the problem? It's driving me crazy!

Comment: Debug the code. One of the forced unwrapped optionals is most likely `nil`.

Comment: Unwrapping is not the problem

Comment: Then what is the specific reason of the exception?

Comment: Where can i find it? i see only : libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: How do you know that unwrapping is not the problem if you don't even know the proper reason? ;-) Usually pressing the continue button in the debugger prints the reason in the console.

Comment: Yes but i pressed it a lot of time, no more specific error.
And i know that the unwrapping is not the problem beacuse if i print this raw of code without unwrapping it the error is the same

Comment: You need to set the exception breakpoint for the continue button functionality.

Comment: already done...

Comment: I am having the same issue! The bug is happening when calling `instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)` from a `UINib` object. There is no more clue as to what is going on and this is an apple method!